# multithreaded csv reader + inserter in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, csv, oledb, advantage-database-server

my idea was to start 2 different threads which is a little bit problematic, one of those reads whole filedirectory and reads every file with jet oledb plugin, another thread which is called write, inserts all lines that have been read into sql database.
this here are my global variables:

```
  Public Class SQL_Data_Form
    Public getData As DataTable
#Region "Functions"
    Private _table As String = "" 'tabelle für inserts
    Private read, write As Thread
    Private db As New DBUmgebung.cdb
    Private oSQL As New DBUmgebung.cdb.SQL()

    Private Delegate Sub AsyncHandler(ByVal file As String)
    Private AsyncReader As AsyncHandler
    Private AsyncWriter As AsyncHandler
```

and this here is the button which triggers the execution:

```
Private Sub btnAusfuehren_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAusfuehren.Click

    Dim ListPathFiles As List(Of String) = ListFiles.GetFileList(TextBox1.Text, False) 

    For Each filePath As String In ListPathFiles 
        Dim fileInfo As New FileInfo(filePath)

        _table = fileInfo.Name.Replace(fileInfo.Extension, String.Empty)

        Try
            View("connect", 15, "")
            Dim conn As New DBUmgebung.cdb
            View("connection successful", 20, "")
            View("check the table... ", 25, _table)
            If Not conn.executeCommand("SELECT * FROM " & _table) Then
                Throw New Exception("Table missing")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            rtbSql.Focus()
            View("closed", 100, "")

            Exit Sub
        End Try

        GetCSVFile(filePath)

        AsyncReader = New AsyncHandler(AddressOf GetCSVFile)
        AsyncReader.BeginInvoke(filePath, AddressOf AsyncReaderCallback, Nothing)


        read = New Thread(AddressOf Me.GetCSVFile)
        read.IsBackground = True
        read.Start()

        Thread.Sleep(100)
        InsertCSVFile(filePath)

        If read.IsAlive Then
            write = New Thread(AddressOf Me.InsertCSVFile)
            write.IsBackground = True
            write.Start()
        Else
            Throw New ApplicationException("process read exception")
            rtbSql.Focus()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

it lists all files in directory at first and then starts the thread read which only reads all files with oledb plugin here:

```
Private Function GetCSVFile(ByVal file As String) As DataTable

    Try
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & TextBox1.Text & ";Extended Properties=""TEXT;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""
        Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConStr)

        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from " & _table & ".csv", conn)
        da.Fill(dt)
        getData = dt
    Catch ex As OleDbException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return getData
End Function
```

so thereafter it passes all the data to thread write which inserts it in sql database:

```
Private Sub InsertCSVFile(ByVal filepath As String)

        Dim BigData As DataTable = GetCSVFile(filepath)

        View("read Filetable", 30, "")

        View("inserting... ", 35, "")

        For i = BigData.Rows.Count To 0 Step -1



            Try
                oSQL.init()
                oSQL.ausfuehrenSQLDT(DBUmgebung.cdb.KSQLCommand.INSERT, _table, "", BigData)

                Dim dtRow As DataRow = BigData.NewRow

                BigData.Rows.Add(dtRow)
                DataGridView1.Refresh()
                Application.DoEvents()

            Catch sqlEx As SqlException
                MessageBox.Show(sqlEx.Message)

                rtbSql.Focus()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                rtbSql.Focus()
            End Try
            DataGridView1.DataSource = BigData
            View("closed", 100, "")
        Next
    End Sub
```

so im still struggling with the issue how to parametrize the inserts, this one was my first idea:

```
Private Sub GetTypesSQL()
        Dim dtInserts As DataTable = db.GetDataTable("SELECT TOP 0 * FROM " & _table)
        Dim ListOfTypes As New List(Of System.Type)

        For Each _col As DataColumn In dtInserts.Columns
            Dim _type As System.Type = _col.DataType
            ListOfTypes.Add(_type)
        Next
        Dim _wert1 As String = "11.11.2011"
        Dim _type1 As System.Type = ListOfTypes.Item(1)
        If DateTime.TryParse(_wert1, New Date) Then
        End If
    End Sub
```

it checks through query which datatype every column has but it's not proper enough to check all data types and jet oledb reader skips lines sometimes, does anyone have clue what is the main problem here?

Comment: forgot to mention, there are some characters that need to be replaced, how do i handle that because my function accepts only strings `Public Sub ReplaceChars(ByRef _Rest() As String)
        For i As Integer = 0 To _Rest.Length - 1
            _Rest(i) = _Rest(i).Replace("\t", Constants.vbTab).Replace("\n", Constants.vbLf).
                                Replace("\r", Constants.vbCr).Replace("\""", """").Replace("\\", "\")

        Next
    End Sub`